# Не могу вывести в типе double значение vx и vy

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.x

Не могу вывести в типе double значение vx и vy.
Моя первая полноценная программа на Python. Версия 2.7

```
    # -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x500')
root.title('Программа')

frame1=Frame(root,width=300,heigh=300,bg='green',bd=5)
frame2=Frame(root,width=200,heigh=300,bg='white',bd=5)


tx1 = Text(frame2, font=('times',12),width=20,height=1,wrap=WORD)
tx2 = Text(frame2, font=('times',12),width=20,height=1,wrap=WORD)
tx3 = Text(frame2, font=('times',12),width=20,height=1,wrap=WORD)
tx4 = Text(frame2, font=('times',12),width=20,height=1,wrap=WORD)

label1 = Label(frame2, text="Координата x в пикселях")
label2 = Label(frame2, text="Координата y в пикселях")
label3 = Label(frame2, text="vx")
label4 = Label(frame2, text="vy")


label1.pack()
tx1.pack(expand=NO,fill=BOTH)
label2.pack()
tx2.pack(expand=NO,fill=BOTH)
label3.pack()
tx3.pack(expand=NO,fill=BOTH)
label4.pack()
tx4.pack(expand=NO,fill=BOTH)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()



def getXY(event):


    tx1.delete('1.0', END)
    tx2.delete('1.0', END)
    tx3.delete('1.0', END)
    tx4.delete('1.0', END)
    getx = event.x
    gety = event.y
    x = getx
    y = gety
    vx = x/300 + 4
    vy = y/300 + 4


    tx1.insert(1.0, getx)
    tx2.insert(1.0, gety)
    tx3.insert(1.0, vx)
    tx4.insert(1.0, vy)



frame1.bind('<Button-1>', getXY)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А проблема-то в чем именно?

Comment: Округляет при выводе переменные vx и vy( вывод в tx3 и tx4, соответственно). Выводит 4, а по задумке там - 4,xx

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В python2 при делении целого на целое с помощью `/` результат будет целым числом. Чтобы получить дробное число, вам нужно либо делимое, либо делитель превратить в float:

```
x = 123
print x/300 + 4  # 4
print float(x)/300 + 4  # 4.41
print x/300.0 + 4  # 4.41
```

(http://ideone.com/Cxx3zp)

Comment: Всем большое спасибо. Заработало! c float=)

Answer (score 0):

`vx = float(x)/300 + 4` так должно работать, например. Думаю, есть более красивые способы.